# Submersions and induced homomorphism on fundamental groups

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose that $M$ and $B$ are two smooth manifolds and $\Pi:M\rightarrow B$ a submersion (and onto). Fixed $x\in M$ and $b\in B$, is the induced homomorphism $\Pi_{\#}:\pi_{1}(M,x)\rightarrow \pi_{1}(B,b)$ also onto?
I think so if we assume that the fibres are connected, but I am not sure.

This is my argument. If $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow B$ is a parametrization of an element of $\pi_1(B,b)$, using that $\Pi$ is a submersion, it is clear that locally we can lift $\gamma$ to $M$, obtaining a finite number of curves $\alpha_i:J_i\rightarrow M$ such that $\Pi(\alpha_i(t))=\gamma(t)$ for all $t\in J_i$, where $J_i$ are closed intervals with $\cup_i J_i=[0,1]$ and $J_i\cap J_{i+1}=\{one point \}$. The problem is that $\alpha_i$ does not need to glue with $\alpha_{i+1}$, but this can be solved easily taking into account that the end point of $\alpha_i$ and the starting point of $\alpha_{i+1}$ are in the same fibre.

Indeed. Since we assume that the fibres are connected, we can take an auxiliary curve $\beta_i$ in the fibre joining the end point of $\alpha_i$ and the starting point of $\alpha_{i+1}$. Composing, we obtain a loop $\sigma$ in $M$ such that $\Pi_{\#}([\sigma])=[\gamma]$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not true! Try $\pi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{S}^1$ defined by $\pi(t)=e^{it}$, this is a onto submersion, but the induced homomorphism is not onto.

Comment: @DiegoMath: The OP stipulated that the fibers are connected.

Comment: I think you need a little more justification for the existence of the $\alpha_i$.  You could use for example the regular value theorem (which maybe you implicitly are).

Comment: I haven't  checked your proof but I have provided an answer confirming the result under the topological supplementary hypothesis of properness.

Answer (score 0):

If $\Pi:M\to B$ is a fiber bundle, we associate to it a [long exact sequence of homotopy groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group#Long_exact_sequence_of_a_fibration), a fragment of which is $$   \cdots \to \pi_1(M,x)\to \pi_1(B,b)\to \pi_0(F,x)\to \cdots $$ where $F=\Pi^{-1}(b)$ is the fiber over $b$.
Hence if $F$ is connected, then  $\pi_0(F,x)=0 $ and we indeed have surjectivity of $ \pi_1(M,x)\to \pi_1(B,b) $.

But is $\Pi$ a fibration when $\Pi$ is a submersion?

The answer is yes if we assume thar $\Pi$ is a proper map: this is [Ehresmann's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann%27s_theorem).
Summing up, we have in your situation the desired surjectivity on fundamental groups under the supplementary topological hypothesis of properness.

Comment: Thanks you all. Georges Elencwajg, I have already known  the Ehresmann's theorem, but I would like to know if the surjectivity is assured for any submersion. I have not found this result, but I think it is quite direct.